# Remove pixels from one raster to another

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, landsat-8

In the following images, the first one has only 2 classes of pixels. I would like to remove **Image's 1**, class 1 (white pixels) completely from **Image 2**. As a result, **Image 2** will have null values in the position of white pixels from Image 1. How can I do that using raster calculator on ArcGIS Pro?

**Image 1: Values above 1 and bellow 0 of SMI_2021 raster**
[image]
**Image 2: Soil Moisture Index with valid range 0 to 1**
[image]

Comment: Con(image1==0, image2)

Comment: How can I use multiple statements inside con? For instance, looking at image 2 how can I replace all values bellow 0 and above 1 with null? @FelixIP

Comment: Con(A>=0,1)×Con(A<=1,A)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subtract 1 from pixel values of raster 1 and muliply by -1: by this, you invert value: 1 results in 0, 0 results in 1. Then divide this with the pixel values of image 2. Division by 0 (for initial white pixels) should return null values.

Comment: B/(1 - A) is less convoluted, but still too much compared to conditional function.